# Python Incorrect AES key length despite passing the a 32 bytes bytearray

Tags: python, aes, valueerror, pycryptodome

I have a specific AES key that I have to work with which is `10h,10h,10h,"A",10h,10h,10h,"AAA",10h,10h,10h,10h,10h,10h,10h,10h,10h,"A",10h,"A",10h,10h,"AA",10h,"A",10h,"A",10h,"A"`

I have to use this key to encrypt a message. In python I covert it to `"\x10,\x10,\x10,A,\x10,\x10,\x10,AAA,\x10,\x10,\x10,\x10,\x10,\x10,\x10,\x10,\x10,A,\x10,A,\x10,\x10,AA,\x10,A,\x10,A,\x10,A"` but I get ValueError: Incorrect AES key length (60 bytes).

I tried encoding the key in a different way like `key = bytearray("\x10,\x10,\x10,A,\x10,\x10,\x10,AAA,\x10,\x10,\x10,\x10,\x10,\x10,\x10,\x10,\x10,A,\x10,A,\x10,\x10,AA,\x10,A,\x10,A,\x10,A".encode('utf-8'))` but I still get a same key length error.

What can I do in this case?

This is my code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

msg = b"<input><type=\"update\"/></input>"
key = bytearray("\x10,\x10,\x10,A,\x10,\x10,\x10,AAA,\x10,\x10,\x10,\x10,\x10,\x10,\x10,\x10,\x10,A,\x10,A,\x10,\x10,AA,\x10,A,\x10,A,\x10,A".encode('utf-8'))

print(key)

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM)
encrypted_msg = cipher.encrypt(msg)
print(encrypted_msg)
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this edit? Do you want to use a different encryption key? Add a comment then.

Answer (score 2):

How about using bytes instead?

```py
#pip install pycryptodome
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

msg = b"<input><type=\"update\"/></input>"
key = bytearray(b"\x10\x10\x10A\x10\x10\x10AAA\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10A\x10A\x10\x10AA\x10A\x10A\x10A")

print(key)

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM)
encrypted_msg = cipher.encrypt(msg)
print(encrypted_msg)
```

This seems to be working.
Please note that you can also use bytes.fromhex, which is more readable

```py
#pip install pycryptodome
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

msg = b"<input><type=\"update\"/></input>" 
key = bytearray(bytes.fromhex("1010104110101041414110101010101010101041104110104141104110411041"))

print(key)

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM)
encrypted_msg = cipher.encrypt(msg)
print(encrypted_msg)
```

Now, the good question: why does this happen?
Well, utf-8 encodes the non ascii characters differently, pseudocode:

```
 '\x80    \x81    \x82    \x83    \x84    \x85    \x86    \x87    \x88    \x89    \x8a    \x8b    \x8c    \x8d    \x8e    \x8f    \x90    \x91    \x92    \x93    \x94    \x95    \x96    \x97    \x98    \x99    \x9a    \x9b    \x9c    \x9d    \x9e    \x9f    \xa0    \xa1    \xa2    \xa3    \xa4    \xa5    \xa6    \xa7    \xa8    \xa9    \xaa    \xab    \xac    \xad    \xae    \xaf    \xb0    \xb1    \xb2    \xb3    \xb4    \xb5    \xb6    \xb7    \xb8    \xb9    \xba    \xbb    \xbc    \xbd    \xbe    \xbf    '.encode()
b'\xc2\x80\xc2\x81\xc2\x82\xc2\x83\xc2\x84\xc2\x85\xc2\x86\xc2\x87\xc2\x88\xc2\x89\xc2\x8a\xc2\x8b\xc2\x8c\xc2\x8d\xc2\x8e\xc2\x8f\xc2\x90\xc2\x91\xc2\x92\xc2\x93\xc2\x94\xc2\x95\xc2\x96\xc2\x97\xc2\x98\xc2\x99\xc2\x9a\xc2\x9b\xc2\x9c\xc2\x9d\xc2\x9e\xc2\x9f\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa1\xc2\xa2\xc2\xa3\xc2\xa4\xc2\xa5\xc2\xa6\xc2\xa7\xc2\xa8\xc2\xa9\xc2\xaa\xc2\xab\xc2\xac\xc2\xad\xc2\xae\xc2\xaf\xc2\xb0\xc2\xb1\xc2\xb2\xc2\xb3\xc2\xb4\xc2\xb5\xc2\xb6\xc2\xb7\xc2\xb8\xc2\xb9\xc2\xba\xc2\xbb\xc2\xbc\xc2\xbd\xc2\xbe\xc2\xbf'
```

Comment: Thank you but it gives me this error: TypeError: Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code

Comment: You haven't copied the whole code, msg must be a bytes object too.

Comment: @Code Gray, please note that this way it's no longer clear why the code isn't working...

Comment: Feel free to adjust as necessary. The point of the edits was to remove the original key, which was private information.

Comment: True, but I'm afraid you need to clear the history of this post then ...

Comment: We are working on that. :-) Ran into an obscure bug in the moderator tooling. Sorry for the noise/disruption!